# ReactJs not rendering anything on page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've been working with the react router dom and I keep seeing a blank white page on my screen.

```
App.js:

import React from 'react';
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld';
import { HashRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Home />
      <Route path="/notes" exact element={HelloWorld} />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/testHome" style={{ color: 'blue', fontSize: '20px' }}>
        Go to Notes
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

HelloWorld.js:

```
import React from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

When I simply display the components in app.js, I can clearly see the hello world element on the screen, the problem is when I use react router. When I use react router I just see a blank white page. Can anyone help me solve the issue?

Comment: you should follow the [doc](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-hash-router) when create routes in your `App.js` file.

Comment: they have [examples](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/dev/examples/basic/src/App.tsx) you should take a look.

Comment: There will be an error in your console about how only `<Route>` elements are allowed as children of `<Router>`

Comment: @Phil I think you are thinking of the relationship between the `Routes` and `Route` components.

Comment: @DrewReese you're completely correct

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues:

1. The `Route` component isn't being rendered by a `Routes` (*or other `Route` component in the case of nested routes*).
2. The `element` prop takes a `React.ReactNode` prop value, a.k.a. JSX.

To resolve import the `Routes` component and wrap the `Route` component and render the `HelloWorld` component as JSX.

```
import React from 'react';
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld';
import {
  HashRouter as Router,
  Routes, // <-- import Routes
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Home />
      <Routes> // <-- wrap rendered routes
        <Route
          path="/notes"
          element={<HelloWorld />} // <-- render as JSX
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```